# Is the string normalized?

Tags: python, unicode

Is there a standard or clean way in Python of determining if a string is normalized, let's say using `Normalizer.Form.NFKD`?

For example, in my current approach, first I normalize the string, and then compare it to the original one. If they are the same, I concluded that my string was normalized, otherwise it was not.

```
>>> word = u'cómo'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', word) == word
False
>>> word = u'como'
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', word) == word
True
```

Comment: Sounds likes a good plan to me.

Comment: That's how I'd do it.

Comment: Sure, makes sense. Was there some reason you didn't just use this? Did it pass your tests?

Comment: Just wanted to know if it was the optimal way to do it. I know that in Golang there's a function named `IsNormalString` that does the check for you, so I was wondering if Python had something similar. Thanks for all your answers :)